# Verify that the Auth cookie was generated by the current Session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, session-cookies

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. In this application the user launches a URL supplied from an email that contains a token with a few parameters encrypted. One of the parameters for example is a mobile phone number.

The application then uses custom security logic to send a 4 digit code as an SMS to the mobile phone number attached.

At this point the user is presented with a screen asking for a 4 digit code. In the background ASP.NET has set the `ASP.Net_SessionId` cookie on the user's browser. This is a standard ASP.NET feature to supply this is on the first request.

Once the user enters the 4 digit code and it is confirmed to be correct the HTTP response will set the `ASPXAUTH` cookie.

This all works fine. However a security concern has been raised. A bypass technique has surfaced by which:

1. Have 2 different application URLs, URL A, URL B.
2. Launch URL A. This will provide the attacker with `ASP.Net_SessionId A`.
3. Launch URL B. Then enter the known 4 digit code. This will provide the attacker with `ASP.Net_SessionId B` and `ASPXAUTH B`.
4. The attacker can then bypass the security code screen on URL A by doing a GET to an authenticated page using the `ASPXAUTH B` cookie in the GET request.

While this is not a massive concern due to the amount of pieces required to be successfully in play here, there is question here: **How, in any given HTTP request, do we confirm that the passed `ASPXAUTH` cookie was generated by the passed `ASP.Net_SessionId`?**

My intuition leads me to a a fairly crude solution by which you could store the value of the `ASPXAUTH` on a user's session object and then compare this on every request. **Is there a smarter way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with Authentication vs Authorization.  Having a valid ASP.NET session doesn't ensure you know who the user is.  There are lots of ways to do this, in short, you need to verify the identity of the user in the session in your application.

[Security, Authentication, and Authorization with ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/)

Comment: It's true that having a valid ASP.NET session doesn't ensure you know who the user is. However this would only apply to authenticated users. If the auth cookie is considered completely independent entity and it either is valid or isn't. What a attacker combining a valid auth token with any valid session token. Is the solution I recommended here not effective or am I missing something entirely?

Comment: All bets are off if the attacker has compromised valid session cookies.  There is nothing you can do.